# What's happened to the Masamune to make it so evil?

Tags: chrono-trigger, chrono-cross

in *Chrono Cross* the Masamune is shown as an evil sword that draws out the wielder's dark desires and generally causes them to kill their allies.

yet in *Chrono Trigger* this never happened to Glenn or Cyrus and if what was happening with it in *Chrono Cross* was because of how the Masamune was created from the Red Dagger being used on the Mammon Machine (and thus influenced in some way by Larvos) then the 2 of them should have been feeling the effects already since they wielded the sword before the events of *Chrono Cross*

So what's happened to the Masamune to make it so evil?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chrono Cross or Chrono Trigger, but those could actually be different swords. Masamune was a very famous historical sword maker, so his swords are known as "a Masamune" in the same way violins made by Stradivarius are known as "a Stradivarius." Strangely, in Japanese video games, the best sword or near best sword in the game are often called Masamune even if they were not supposed to be made by Masamune, and he may not even exist in that game's universe. It's like the name Masamune is near mythological, and synonymous with "really awesome sword."

Comment: @Kai In Chrono Trigger at least, the Masamune is one specific sword. I'm assuming it's the same in Chrono Cross.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the cause was the fall of Guardia kingdom and theft  of aformentioned sword. 
https://www.chronocompendium.com/Term/Fall_of_Guardia.html